# Saving screenshots to a path with a space in it

Tags: finder, screenshot

I know I should run

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /Users/kirkstrobeck/Dropbox\ \(Personal\)/Sync/Pictures/Screenshots
killall SystemUIServer
```

To change my screenshot destination, but it rejects it. Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to explain your question better so we can help you. Otherwise, it is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OP asked is, when making a screenshot in OSX(by <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>), the file is saved to desktop folder by default, and OP wants to change that location.

I created a similar folder but also having problem set it using "defaults write", however, since it's saved in a plist, we can modify this file directly.

The plist is located at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screencapture.plist`, modify it accordingly using a plist editor and then `killall SystemUIServer` from terminal or logout/login.

If the file is not available by default, run

`defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /Users/xxx`

to create one first, then modify.

Tested and confirmed to work.

[image]

Comment: Hmm .. doesn’t work

Comment: I tested myself before posting, osx yosemite. Can you take a screenshot of your current com.apple.screencapture.plist file?

Comment: make sure to replace xxx in the screenshot with your own username, other than that, I can't think of anything wrong...

Comment: It looks like it required a restart! thx